# How do I get an object to stay put when keyframing child of constraint influence?

Tags: constraints, keyframes

I am a new animator doing some Minecraft animations. One problem I ran into was that when I keyframed influence at 1 and next frame at 0, it moves drastically when I move it to 0. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Before I set it to 0 (sword):
[image: influence at 1 on the constraint]

After I set it to 0 (the sword moves drastically):
[image: influence at 0 on the constraint, sword drastically out of place]

Answer (score 0):

You animated the "influence" on your "Child of" constraint. On frame 0, it was set to Influence of 1.00, but then its influence goes all the way to 0.00 at frame 1. 
This means that you must have accidentally animated the influence from 1.00 to 0.00 in the animation. So, just reset the Influence value back to 1.00 at frame 1.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this, but it didnt work. I cleared the keyframes, and set the influence to 1 at frame 0 and 1, and I keyframed it again 1 frame before I keyframed it at 0, but it still moved like crazy

Answer (score 0):

First place the object, then adding it with "Child of" will move it somewhere.
Do not move the object back, just hit "Set Inverse" and the object will go back to its initial place.